# Transition between desired amounts

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

An element has class `slider-item`:

```
.slider-item{
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 100s ease;
  transition-delay: 800ms;
 }
```

When i click on a button ,i want the element to transition between `translateY(-100%)` and `translateY(0)`.

I add classes `prev-version` and `next` by javascript respectively:

```
.slider-item.prev-version{
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: none;
}
.slider-item.next{
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 100s ease;
  transition-delay: 800ms;
}
```

But i see transition happens between `translateY(100%)` and `translateY(0)`. `next` class overrides `transform: translateY(-100%);` in `prev-version` class. Please help me what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to try would probably be to use Vanilla JavaScript, jQuery, or some other type of framework to directly edit and change the CSS attributes.

So for example the jQuery version would be:

```
$("#slider-item.next").css("transform:translateY(0)");
```

Keep in mind you would need to add logic so that if the attribute was 100 it would change it back to 0 and then if it was 0 it would change it back to 100.

w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Answer (score 1):

I might didn't understand your question but seems that you can use `css animation` for this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () { document.querySelector('.slider-item').classList.add('example'); });
```

```css
button {position: fixed; bottom: 10vh} /* just for demo */
.slider-item{
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 100s ease;
  transition-delay: 800ms;
}
.example {
  animation: example 3s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes example {
  from {transform: translateY(-100%);}
  to {  transform: translateY(100%);} /* should be the same as the value declared initial on .slider-item */
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-item">Slider Item</div>
<button>Click</button>
```